# Command to check trust relation between 2 domains

Tags: active-directory, trust-relationship

Good Day,

Do we have any command where we can check the trust relationship between 2 domains.
Example :
lets consider there is a domains called xyz.1.com and abc.1.com how can we know whether there is a trust between xyz and abc domains any direct command we have for this .

Regards,
Vikas Chandra.C

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter {objectClass -eq "trustedDomain"} -Properties TrustPartner,TrustDirection,trustType | FT Name,TrustPartner,TrustDirection,TrustType
```

per [Viewing the Trusts for a Domain](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378797(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Thank You For the Command will give it a try and post the results

Comment: This also requires the AD PowerShell module, usually installed along with RSAT.

Comment: @Massimo yes but you can run the session remotely requiring no install whatsoever.  No powershell module should ever require local install if it's available remotely

Comment: Correct. But this would make the command quite a bit more complex. As you posted it, it can only work where RSAT/AD is installed.

Comment: I can't post all 50 ways you can use posh to accomplish a given task. The command given is the Microsoft preffered method from the article on how to search.  If you wanted the CIM version, or do this from Linux, it's presumed you understand how to invoke the command from those environments.

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for is [netdom](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835085(v=ws.10).aspx).

To check whether a trust is correctly in place between two domains, you can use the `verify` option:

```
netdom trust abc.1.com /d:xyz.1.com /verify
netdom trust xyz.1.com /d:abc.1.com /verify
```

You can also check if a two-way trust relationship is in place using a single command:

```
netdom trust abc.1.com /d:xyz.1.com /verify /twoway
```

Comment: ok may I know how are the parameters passed . netdom xyz abc verify ?

Comment: Just read the link; I've also added examples.

Comment: You can also use NetBIOS names (`abc` and `xyz`), but it's usually better to use FQDNs.

Comment: netdom trust abc.1.com /d:xyz.1.com /verify
netdom trust xyz.1.com /d:abc.1.com /verify the commands can be given only on the server where ADDS is installed ? or can we run the command @ our local machine

Comment: You can run it on a domain controller or on any domain computer where the Active Directory administration tools are installed.

Comment: Note that netdom requires the RSAT in win7 and above.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the exact command to use perform the task requested by the OP... I really don't understand why there is a downvote. Whoever did it, would you care to explain please?

Comment: @vikas if you found the answer hekpful, please upvote and/or accept it.